# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null

Tags: java

A lot of people have already asked this question, but I can't just solve it. I'm trying to do a 2d Game following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wT9uNGzMEM4&t=162s) tutorial, now I'm in the sprite character section, and I'm adding images to my GamePanel.

Here's the StackTrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at java.desktop/javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1356)
    at entity.Player.getPlayerImage(Player.java:53)
    at entity.Player.<init>(Player.java:25)
    at main.GamePanel.<init>(GamePanel.java:29)
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:17)
```

This is the critical Method:

```
public void getPlayerImage() {
        try {
            up1 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/res/player/boy_up_1.png"));
            up2 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/res/player/boy_up_2.png"));
            down1 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/res/player/boy_down_1.png"));
            down2 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/res/player/boy_down_2.png"));
            left1 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/res/player/boy_left_1.png"));
            left2 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/res/player/boy_left_2.png"));
            right1 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/res/player/boy_right_1.png"));
            right2 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/res/player/boy_right_2.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to provide the code where the exception occured `main.Main.main(Main.java:17)`

Comment: It says that you pass null to the `ImageIO.read` method. Just use a debugger, verify that it's correct.

Comment: `getResourceAsStream` will return `null` if the resource is not found or not accessible - documentation: *"null if no resource with this name is found ..."* - is the `res/`  folder on the CLASSPATH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `getPlayerImage()` you probably use the wrong path for your images. This results in `getClass().getResourceAsStream` being `null`. This then results in giving the `read()`-method `null` as instead of a File.

Snippet rom ImageIO:

```
/** @exception IllegalArgumentException if {@code input} is
 * {@code null}.
 * @exception IOException if an error occurs during reading or when not
 * able to create required ImageInputStream.
 */
public static BufferedImage read(File input) throws IOException {
    if (input == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("input == null!");
    }
    //...    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have set the `res` folder as your resources folder in your IDE?

If it is the projects resource folder you can try to recreate the project. I had a similar problem and recreating the Project worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).